# Hapi.js - How do I get a serialized representation of a rendered view

Tags: javascript, node.js, caching, hapi.js

I would like to [cache](https://github.com/hapijs/catbox) rendered views in [Hapi.js](http://hapijs.com/) (using the [Vision plugin](https://github.com/hapijs/vision) for rendering view templates), but haven't been able to find out how to do it. What I need to know is

1. *How do I get a serialized representation of a rendered view, which I can cache?*
2. *How should I reply to the client with a serialized rendering that I got from the cache?*

Currently, cache-less, my code for rendering views in response to client requests is quite straightforward, basically like this (irrelevant code left out):

```
// renderIndex is a Hapi.js request handler
let renderIndex = (request, reply) => {
  [...]
  reply.view('serverSideIndex') // serverSideIndex is a .pug template
}
```

Here I'm using `reply.view` to directly respond with a rendered view to the client. I need to inject caching logic here instead however, in order to not render more often than necessary and thereby optimize performance.

Let me know if I need to provide more code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding how to render a view into a serialized representation, it's done through the [request.render](https://github.com/hapijs/vision/blob/master/API.md#serverrendertemplate-context-options-callback) method:

```
let renderedView = request.render('serverSideIndex')
```

As for responding with this serialized rendering back to the client, it's simply done by passing it to the reply function:

```
reply(renderedView)
```